# compilation error when using boost framework and opencv in ios project

Tags: ios, boost, compiler-errors

I need to use boost framework in my iOS project. My first mission was getting boost to work for Ios. I tried using this script

http://goodliffe.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/building-boost-framework-for-ios-iphone.html

but wasn't able to build due to lipo errors (?) and couldn't figure out how to solve it. I looked for a precompiled framework and came accross this project on github:

https://github.com/danomatika/ofxLua

There is an Ios version of boost included in the lib section. So I tried using it in my project

but now when I build my project I am getting these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "vtable for boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::path_locale() in boost(path.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      MatlabIO::uncompressVariable(unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&) in MatlabIO.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      MatlabIO::uncompressVariable(unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&) in MatlabIO.o
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      MatlabIO::uncompressVariable(unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&) in MatlabIO.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also want to make clear that I installed boost using

```
sudo port install boost
```

and under my xcode project I am not linking to /usr/local/include/boost/ or something like that. It seems that it is compiling with incorrect architecture.

Any solution for this? Maybe the framework isn't compiled for Ios? Or is my project not referencing the correct version

Comment: Build that library for both, simulator and device - then join both versions using lipo and use the resulting (universal) library within your app.

Comment: wan't able to build. do you have a script or somewhere to download?

Comment: See my answer @AvnerBarr. Build scripts included (also the static libs, see releases for a plug and play option) (Especially for a OpenFrameworks project ;D)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BOOST 1.57.0 with ofxiOSBoost static libraries and headers:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

Releases for libc++ (c++11), libstdc++.

All build scripts are in the /scripts folder (updated Peter Goodliffe script)